# Ejecución remota de un programa Java

Tags: java, eclipse

Estoy intentando ejecutar un programa Java remotamente. Utilizando el IDE **Eclipse**, creo un proyecto Java desde mi PC (S.O = WINDOWS) en un servidor X (S.O = LINUX), y utilizando la vista **Remote System Explorer**, con el **SSH Terminals** puedo ejecutar , a través de la línea de comando, la Clase que contiene el método main.
Ahora bien, al ejecutarlo, me salta un error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: MiClase (Unsupported major.minor version 52.0)
```

El cual hace referencia a la versión del jre. Localmente desarrolle utilizando jdk 1.8, y en el servidor se tiene instalado el jdk 1.7.
**La pregunta es, si alguien sabe como tomar el jdk del servidor a la hora de desarrollar el proyecto localmente**. Desde ya Gracias!

Comment: ¿Por qué no desarrollas la aplicación usando el JDK que corresponde al entorno en el que la vas a ejecutar? Es decir, descargas, instalas y configuras el proyecto para que utilice el JDK 1.7 en el entorno de desarrollo. Otra opción sería instalar y habilitar la versión 1.8 en el servidor. Lo de usar el JDK del servidor para desarrollar no creo que se pueda hacer, no tiene mucho sentido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu error significa que estas tratando de ejecutar código compilado para Java 1.8 (major/minor version 52) en una versión posterior. Puedes recompilar tu proyecto de nuevo con *target* Java 1.7 o actualizar la versión de Java donde quieres hacer el despliegue.

La versión *target* puedes configurar en la propiedades de tu proyecto en:

**Java Compiler->Compiler compliance level**

Cambia este nivel desde 1.8 a 1.7 y el nuevo *build* funcionará en Java 1.7

Tambien tienes que tener cuidado con Eclipse y Java 1.8, Eclipse tiene soporte completo para Java 1.8 desde Eclipse Luna, Kepler necesita un parche, antes de eso tu versión *target* no va funcionar como lo configuraste.

Comment: Excelente, funcionó a la perfección. Gracias